# Change a function argument type based on previous argument

Tags: typescript

I have a static function named "`onHook`". This function have two parameters, an `ID` and a `Callback`. My goal is to change the type of the callback argument based on the type of the Hook ID.

For now I managed to get this working :

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAEg9nA1gSQCJQN4Cgq6geRHwAdRgATAGhz0IGEAbOAZwuoF8ssAXAT1NgJEAQQBOAc0ihuzADwAVAHxQAvFBq55UYAA9uocs0FI0AOkIky5KAH5MGvLgCGEgIwAuKM26iAliHFqR0cXcQAmT28-AId2dwctXX0QQ2MUVHMQRhYKW3tgvFCAZk8AIwQGYCcQIIKoUIAWMoqqkFioTxBgADdgUQBuLgAzMBAAY25fOBAoafgkBUUACl9yT3n0yigxpwYGUqcxxE8l0PWhMUkIaTklAEoVZW64VbvsPAB6D6gAKj%20fqBfLCcLBzISyDZmehMVjkZaQjLQnJUKCnCTMB6Kd6fP71dGmYrOFLOfGNPHAerdJy%20BhOUqVIw-b7qdh3IA)

```ts
enum HookID {
    OnOpened,
    OnClosed,
}

type HookArguments<T> = 
    T extends HookID.OnOpened ? {
        arg1: string,
        arg2: string
    }:
    T extends HookID.OnClosed ? {
        arg3: boolean,
        arg4: boolean
    } : never;

function onHook<T>(id: HookID, callback: (arg: HookArguments<T>)=> void){
   // **** //
}

onHook<HookID.OnClosed>(HookID.OnClosed, (args)=>{
    /** args.arg3  and  args.arg4 are availables */  
})
```

But having to declare the enum both on the Generic type and in the ID argument doesn't seem optimal. Is there a way to get the type of the ID parameters and inject it to the Argument generic type ?

Something like this :

```ts
function onHook(id: HookID, callback: (arg: HookArguments<this.id>)=> void){
   // **** //
}

onHook(HookID.OnClosed, (args)=>{
     // **** //
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intent is that the `id` parameter be of the same [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `T` that you use to determine `callback`'s parameter, right?  So let's do that:

```
function onHook<T extends HookID>(
    id: T, callback: (arg: HookArguments<T>) => void
) {
    // **** //
}
```

When you call it, the compiler can now *infer* `T` from the `id` argument, and so `args` automatically gets the type you expect:

```
onHook(HookID.OnClosed, (args) => {
    /* (parameter) args: {
    arg3: boolean;
    arg4: boolean;
     } */
})
```

---

That's the answer to the question as asked, but as an aside, you don't need to use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to define `HookArguments`.  Since you want to map a numeric enum to an arbitrary type, you can use an [object type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types) to capture this, since object types are good at describing mappings from keylike types (a `string`, `number`, or `symbol`, and enums are strings/numbers) to other types.  And then you can just [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) the object type with the enum to look up the associated property:

```
interface HookArguments {
    [HookID.OnOpened]: { arg1: string, arg2: string },
    [HookID.OnClosed]: { arg3: boolean, arg4: boolean }
}

function onHook<K extends HookID>(
  id: K, callback: (arg: HookArguments[K]) => void
) {
    // **** //
}

onHook(HookID.OnClosed, (args) => {
    /* (parameter) args: {
    arg3: boolean;
    arg4: boolean;
     } */
})
```

That behaves the same way for your purposes, but is a more conventional implementation.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAEg9nA1gSQCJQN4Cgq6geRHwAdRgATAGhz0IGEAbOAZwuoF8ssAXAT1NgJEAQQBOAc0ihuzADwAVAHxQAvDVzyowAB7dQ5ZoKRoAdIRJlyUAPyZ1eXAEMJARgBcUZt1EBLEOOoHB2dxACYPL19-e3YoN3tNHT0QAyMUVDMQRhYKGzsgvBCAZg8AIwQGYEcQQIKoEIAWMoqqkBi4qBBgADdgUQBuLgAzMBAAY24fOBAoafgkBS1dfUN59MUACnsfcg95SigxxwYGUscxxA8NkI81sUkIaTklAEpVZW64Haw37AcAen+UAAVKDgVBAVhOHMhBs1qZ6ExWFQoNcJMw3iplH88P9wRtiM5HI89KI3iFmB4cU4JCUoOU4JVqoNghImvSWsz7FBYsD-lCXlwsCBicBmISxsAoAAhYDcUn5PB+UlDc5Su4SKQgGSKgoAbXhGXMpC65AAulT6q4It4-AErWEbVFxDzavrDZlssiLZgHXSGUyag72QHWjyYlwHCNxpNprMQGtZABpJbJVKGzY7DxJg5HE5nC5XG5pe5amR6pNmzEfL7kX7c3FAsHgyEOTgOGFIOFCBFZJFsVEU6u6oJ48EUkzFJwpGniZiTtlWqWObqOHwMRylSqGPkxQWcIVAA)

Comment: Great one ! Worked perfectly and you even improved my first attempt ! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Have `onHook<T extends HookID>()` instead of only being a generic of `<T>`, then set the first arg as type `T`, this will still require it to be HookID.

```
function onHook<T extends HookID>(id: T, callback: (arg: HookArguments<T>)=> void){
   // **** //
}
```